# Can I use PhoneGap to build more than 1 closed apps for free?

Tags: cordova

When I try to run PhoneGap according to the official site, this is how it looks:

```
C:\Users\RiMMER\app1>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] PhoneGap/Build Login
[phonegap] Sign up at build.phonegap.com
 [warning] GitHub accounts are unsupported
  [prompt] enter username:
```

On build.phonegap.com it says that a free account can contain only 1 private app.

Is this the only procedure to follow, or is this some special feature which I don't really need and can follow some other way to build apps with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build more then one app for free, but not remotely on build.phonegap.com.
You can build your apps locally.

```
phonegap local build andoird
```

or

```
phonegap local run android
```

But you have to setup your own build environment.

How To setup build environments is described in the platform guides on http://docs.phonegap.com.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides

lg

fastrde

Answer (score 1):

Simple - you can either upgrade your PG Build account to a paid account, or switch to doing local development. You need to download the appropriate SDKs first - and this is documented at the PhoneGap side, but once you do that the command line will run the builds locally instead of on PG BUild.