# Phonegap ios settings window

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have developed a simple PhoneGap application for ios.
This app is mainly a wrapper of a mobile website.
`onDeviceReady` I just do the following:

```
window.open(myURL, '_blank');
```

`myURL:` opens a webview object which refer to a website built for mobile using `jquery-mobile`.
I would like to have the `myURL` be selected from a settings window within the application.

1. How do I add/handle a settings button & window for ios (iphone) using PhoneGap?
2. Is the free PhoneGap build account enough for creating this simple app and publishing it within apple apps itunes store, or do I need to upgrade my account?

Answer (score 1):

if you are more good at `HTML` than `objective-c`, create the settings page as your first page of the phonegap app, i.e in HTML. Then when you get the `myURL` value, just open that in an `inappBrowser`.

Get the `inappBrowser` plugin from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

**Update:**

If you have the SDK for the respective platforms installed, then you can create the project using `cordova/phonegap CLI` and then use your Platforms IDE (`XCode`, `Eclipse`. etc) to build and publish the app. Where as using `phonegap-build`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19877683/3894781) question.